# Getting exception while trying to get FileOutputStream

Tags: java, file-io

We are getting the following exception while trying to get FileOutputStream for a filename:
java.lang.Exception: /var/tmp (Is a directory)

Please suggest what can be the cause of the error.

Code snippet where exception occurs:

```
public static FileOutputStream getFileInternal()
{
String pFilename = "/usr/tmp/";
File f = new File(pFilename);
pFilename = f.getCanonicalPath();
FileOutputStream fo = null;
fo = new FileOutputStream(pFilename, true);
return fo;
}
```

Comment: `/usr/tmp/` is not a file name, use a filename which doesn't end withe a `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"/usr/tmp/"` is a directory.

`FileOutputStream` only writes into regular files, not directories.

You can try something like:

```
String pFilename = "/usr/tmp/output.txt";
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a `FileOutputStream` from a directory. Different from `File`, they only work with actual files.